# Excel Macro: error when pasting - moving down 10 rows - pasting - 10 rows - pasting, etc

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to copy data from three workbooks (one at a time) from the same range (A4:A8) and paste them into a new workbook. The only catch is I'm trying to make the paste part move down by 10 lines each loop.

I'm receiving an error message on the PasteSpecial line. I'm not sure why?

(I'm an Excel macro novice, but I'm giving it a go)

Any guidance/pointers is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Mike.

```
Dim TestWorkbook as variant,
Dim mytest as variant
TestWorkbook= array(“test1”, “test2”, “test3”) ‘3 source files
i = 0
 For Each mytest  In TestWorkbook 
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\ExcelWork\" + TestWorkbook + "_Work.xls"
 Range("a4:a8").Copy
 ActiveWorkbook.Close
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\Result_Workbook.xls"
 Range("l" & 5 + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues `THE PROBLEM IS HERE
 i = i + 10  
Next
```

Comment: What does the error actually say?

Comment: I'm not sure you can keep the copy after the workbook is closed.  Try to paste it before you close the first workbook (of course you'll have to make sure you select the exact sheet you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems fixed 'See comments

```
Sub a()
 Dim TestWorkbook As Variant
 Dim mytest As Variant
 Dim s As String
 TestWorkbook = Array("test1", "test2", "test3")
 i = 1  'Start with 1
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\Result_Workbook.xls" 'open only once
 For Each mytest In TestWorkbook
     s = mytest & ".xls"
     Workbooks.Open "c:\" & s
     Workbooks(s).Activate 'Remember to Activate
     Range("a4:a8").Copy
     ' Now paste properly
     Workbooks("Result_Workbook.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("l" & 5 + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close after pasting
     i = i + 10
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works fine. Thanks for the tips and comments as they're really useful. The using S as string part is also a nice thing to know. Save's me typing time.

Comment: @Mike Glad to know it worked. Always remember the best method to start a Macro is recording the actions and peeping into the automagically generated code.